# Why is QGIS Field calculator button greyed out?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

I'm using QGIS to attempt to calculate the area enclosed by a set of points that I have capture used a GPS device.

I have imported the coordinates from a CSV but when trying to open the field calculator from the layer's attribute table the button is greyed out and cannot be clicked. Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing [image: Calculator not available]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First save the CSV points to a shapefile. Then try the Points2One plugin to convert the points to a polygon. Then you'll be able to use the Field calculator to get the area of the polygon.

Comment: Thanks. I converted the points to a shape but the field calculator is still not available. Do you know why this might be?

http://cl.ly/image/1D1K3F0m1S0e

Comment: CSVs are read only. That's why it's not possible to edit CSV-based layers.

Answer (score 3):

First save the CSV points to a shapefile and then you have to toggle the Editing mode to on.